# Control the disk location of documents in Lucene

Tags: java, lucene

Is there a way I can tell Lucene to store documents in disk in some predefined order?

For instance, I have documents with sparse, but sorted, IDs (i.e. in a `LongField` named `ID`). I want to load them one by one -- sorted -- from Lucene Index. In a perfect world, this will happen magically just by iterating from `0` to `IndexReader.maxDoc()` and loading `IndexReader.document(i)`.

Is this possible?

Comment: What does this have to do with disk location?

Comment: @EJP minimize disk random access.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is possible using a [SortingMergePolicy](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_8_0/misc/org/apache/lucene/index/sorter/SortingMergePolicy.html) that will sort your documents whenever a merge occurs.

Here's an example ([gist](https://gist.github.com/knutwalker/11489359)).

First, you create a SortingMergePolicy:

```
    boolean ascending = false;
    SortField idSortField = new SortField("id", SortField.Type.LONG, ascending);

    SortingMergePolicy sortingMP = new SortingMergePolicy(
            iwc.getMergePolicy(), new Sort(idSortField));
    iwc.setMergePolicy(sortingMP);
```

Then, you index your documents regularly, in whatever order you like

```
    d = new Document();
    d.add(new LongField("id", 4, Field.Store.YES));
    iw.addDocument(d);

    d = new Document();
    d.add(new LongField("id", 2, Field.Store.YES));
    iw.addDocument(d);
```

You just need to force a merge before opening your `IndexReader`

```
    iw.forceMerge(1, true);
```

Now, if you open an `IndexReader` on this, you can iterate you documents from 0 to `IndexReader.maxDoc()` and they will be sorted by your `LongField`.

A few notes:

- This class lives in [lucene-misc](http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Corg.apache.lucene%7Clucene-misc%7C4.8.0%7Cjar), you might have to add this as an additional dependency
- The [API changed](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/LUCENE-5493) with the 4.8.0 release, requiring a `Sort` instead if a `Sorter`
- You can also do live sorting or offline sorting ([example in the gist](https://gist.github.com/knutwalker/11489359#file-so23430775-java))